# NodeJS and Express app with NGINX as a reverse proxy getting 504 gateway time-out error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, passport.js, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to get a NodeJS and Express app running on Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64 using NGINX as a reverse proxy. I am also using Lets Encrypt for SSL. I am getting a "504 Gateway Time-out" error. I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong, mind you that I am pretty new to NGINX. So here is what I have:

The app is located in apps/appname/app.js

```
    app.listen(5000, function(){
     console.log('Express app listening on port 5000');
    });
```

I don't know if any of this matters but might be worth noting, here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Blah blah blah",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-messages": "^1.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^5.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.4",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.4"
  }
}
```

I am using pm2 to run the app as a proccess.

```
┌──────┬──────┬────────┬───┬─────┬───────────┐
│ Name │ mode │ status │ ↺ │ cpu │ memory    │
├──────┼──────┼────────┼───┼─────┼───────────┤
│ app  │ fork │ online │ 0 │ 0%  │ 96.4 MB   │
└──────┴──────┴────────┴───┴─────┴───────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

The NGINX config file is located in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default and looks like this:

```
# HTTP - redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        # Enable HTTP/2
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.something.com something.com;

        # Use the Let's Encrypt certificates
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.something.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.something.com/privkey.pem;

        # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout 5s;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload”;
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

I have tried a few different things to try to get my app working;

1) Because why not??? When I do this I get 502 Bad Gateway.

```
proxy_connect_timeout       300;
proxy_send_timeout          300;
proxy_read_timeout          300;
send_timeout                300;
```

2)

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

Just to note, I am using UFW and have the following:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Even when I disable the firewall I still cannot access the app. I still get a 504 Gateway Time-out.
Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

After writing this all out I found this trying to run the Mongo Shell:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-02-24T16:40:56.440+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-02-24T16:40:56.446+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Now I am even more confused on what is going on.

Comment: you need to open port 5000 also in your firewall for public access.

Comment: @divsingh
I don't think you're right. Nginx forwards all the HTTP traffic to 5000 internally.

Comment: thanks @TalDelbari I learnt something there about proxy_pass so that i don't need to open application port for public.

Comment: Sorry this took me so long to get back to answer my own question. I just needed to take a break and walk away for about an hour and the answer hit me. I didn't have the Mongo Daemon running and it was causing the app to crash and not respond. As soon as the Mongo daemon was running everything worked perfectly. @TalDelbari you are absolutely correct. That is the exact purpose of having a reverse proxy. You don't want to directly expose your app to the outside world.